# StatsD Metrics setup with Treafik v2.2

Tags: traefik, statsd

I'm not able to receive metrics from Traefik. I'm currently trying to setup the statsd service but I keep receiving the following error and no metrics are available in the host:

```
time="2020-05-17T20:17:32Z" level=info msg="[err write udp 127.0.0.1:60514->127.0.0.1:8125: write: connection refused]" metricsProviderName=statsd
time="2020-05-17T20:17:32Z" level=info msg="[during WriteTo err write udp 127.0.0.1:60514->127.0.0.1:8125: write: connection refused]" metricsProviderName=statsd
```

My current configuration file is the following on the metrics section:

```
[metrics]
  [metrics.statsd]
    address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    addEntryPointsLabels = true
    addServicesLabels = true
    pushInterval = "10s"
    prefix = "traefik"
```

**Traefik version:** 2.2.1 built on 2020-04-29T18:02:09Z

Am i missing something on the metrics configuration? At least this is all required to enable the metrics as per the docs.

Thanks